# show that if $E$ is a linear space and $L \subset E$ is a subspace such that $codimL=1$ then there is $f \in E^{*}$ with $kerf = L$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be a linear space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and let $L \subset E$ be a subspace such that $codimL = 1$.

I want to prove that there is a functional $f \in E^*$ with $kerf = L$.

Since $codimL = 1$ then $E / L = \{\lambda x + L | \lambda \in \mathbb{F} \}$ for some $0 \neq x \in E$.

Equivalently $E = L + W$ where $dimW=1$.

I am not sure how to follow from here, but since $kerF \subset L + W$ then maybe somehow I can take $y \in kerf$ and then $y = v + w$ where $v \in L, u \in w$ and somehow show that $u = 0$ .

Help woukd be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $L \cap W=\{0\}$. Just define $f(v+\lambda x)=\lambda$. Then the kernel of $f$ is $L$.